# Issue with Sass: "Could not find 'sass'"

Tags: ruby, sass, phpstorm, webstorm

I'm trying to get my build flow working, however I cannot seem to get it working. When Sass goes to run after I save a .scss file, I get the following error:

> `/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p545/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/dependency.rb:298:in 'to_specs': Could not find 'sass' (>= 0.a) among 20 total gem(s) (Gem::LoadError)`

I'm not entirely sure what else I would need to provide, but hopefully this helps;

The FileWatcher is pointing to `/Users/Nick/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.2/bin/sass`

```
$ sass -v
Ruby Sass 3.5.6

$ ruby -v
ruby 2.4.2p198 (2017-09-14 revision 59899) [x86_64-darwin17]

$ which sass
/Users/Nick/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.2/bin/sass

$ which ruby
/Users/Nick/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.4.2/bin/ruby
```

Comment: Must be issue with rvm (not the rvm itself but the way how it all works) -- somehow the environment does not match when running in terminal and when executing file watcher command. **P.S.** Can you use node-sass instead?

Comment: The error looks like you're running it under Ruby 1.9.3, but below you're referencing Ruby 2.4.2. Are you sure you haven't switched ruby versions between the two?

Comment: I set the default version to 2.4.2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out the issue was related specifically to `High Sierra 10.13` that is a known bug. I updated to 10.13.6 and updated XCode Tools and everything is working as it should.